# DynamoDB Streams events for a specific column change

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

As per the official documentation
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.html

**Any** change to **any** column of the `dynamoDb` creates a `stream record` in the `DynamoDB` `streams`. I have one use case where I would require the stream/event to be created or triggered only if a `specific column of the item is changed and not other columns`. Is there a way to do this via `config` in `DynamoDB`? Or do I have to filter the events once they are already created, to look for that `specific column change`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to filter the events from the stream. I recommend you take a look at [AWS Lambda event source filtering](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-ddb.html#services-dynamodb-eventsourcemapping) as this will do what you want and the filtering is free. You only pay when your Lambda function is invoked.